# I want to login to my cpanel and update or delete files from cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, database, cpanel

I have got a new task from the office that to login to cpanel using a PHP view page. and after login, I need to upload or delete files in cpanel. can anyone help me out? I'm stuck with my work.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please look into cpanel documentation online or search on internet.

Comment: This sounds like a possible X/Y problem: if you want to automate deleting of files, cPanel is probably not the tool for the job. If the PHP is running on the same server, you can just delete them; if it's a remote server, set up FTP or SFTP access, and delete them that way.

Comment: what i need is a view page with download and uploads button. when download button is clicked it should list all files in public_html folder of cpanel and download it. and when clicking upload button, the selected file should upload to public_html.

Comment: cPanel does not contain files; it is a way for a human user with a web browser to access files on a particular server. When you talk about "public_html folder of cpanel", you're talking about a folder on some server. If that is the server where your PHP code is going to run, you don't need to do anything more than read and write local files; if it is a different server, you need some form of remote file access, such as FTP or SFTP. Either way, you almost certainly don't want to involve cPanel in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Simply login to your cpanel and look for the 'File Manager' link. Open this link and navigate to your directory to delete and upload as much as you want.

Comment: what i need is a view page with download and uploads button. when download button is clicked it should list all files in public_html folder of cpanel and download it. and when clicking upload button, the selected file should upload to public_html.